# I need a link to a good example of JQuery with ajax to send json to a php script

Tags: php, jquery, json

Can someone kindly put a good & simple example of JQuery with ajax to send json to a php script. I need to send json to a php script when page loads. I mean will be lot easy for me if the link contains example using `$(document).ready(function()...` I need a simple example as my problem is not big, & I need a simple solution. Just POST json to php.

thanX a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this visualJquery reference site a lot, sometimes more than the official api

http://visualjquery.com/

I believe you want to use the function $.post()

Answer (score 0):

simple link to start from example :

http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the jQuery documentation.. They even have an article specifically on doing ajax posts: [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)